# file_get_contents() is not doing so

Tags: php, file, image

I have the following

```
$name = basename($_FILES['the_file']['name']);
$size = $_FILES['the_file']['size'];
$contents = $_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name'];

if($size <= 5242880 && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name'])) {
    $picture = file_get_contents($contents);
    echo $picture;
}
```

but nothing is echoed out. Am I doing something incorrect here?

**EDIT:**

I changed my code:

```
$name = basename($_FILES['the_file']['name']);
$size = $_FILES['the_file']['size'];
$contents = $_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name'];

if($size <= 5242880) {
    $picture = file_get_contents($contents);
    echo $picture;
}
```

I removed the `is_uploaded_file()` condition and now it says

`Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/*************.php on line 13`
(I blurred out the path)

which means that the file isn't being uploaded. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that the call to echo $picture is being executed? Changing that to echo '#' . $picture . '#'; will soon tell you, because you'll get a pair of hashes if it *is* getting that far.

Comment: Strange... it doesnt seem to be executing the `if` block.. :(

Comment: Did you check that you're allowing PHP scripts to actually take the 5MB of memory you're allowing the picture to be?

Comment: Yeah, 5MB is my limit, but it shouldn't matter: the file is 700K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you've left out the `enctype` from your form?

```
<form action='...' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Comment: Ah, crap. That's the problem. So simple ._. Thanks.